# Tensorflow multi-label classification with partial unlabel

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I wonder whether tensorflow could distinguish between negative label and unknown label.

For example, in a news classification scenario, I am sure the instance belongs to "sports" and "entertainment", and also sure it doesn't belong to "politics", but not sure it belongs or not to "game".

If I treat these labels with one-hot encoding, in order of "sport", "entertainment", "politics" and "game", it should like:

```
# here I use -1 to represent negative, 0 for unknown
[1, 1, -1, 0]
```

However, if I want to train instance with ["tf. sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits"](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits), it has two types of output: 0 or 1 for neg and pos label.

What I want is "unknown label" don't contribute to loss in BP, is that possible or reasonable in tensorflow?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can label your three classes into three one-hots:

positive: (0, 0, 1)
neutral: (0, 1, 0)
negative: (1, 0, 0)

Comment: 0.5 still influences loss with BP, while I only want it to be ignored

Comment: In reference you can just set a threshold, say 0.4 to 0.6 as the neutral.

Comment: Thanks, but I mean no matter what to set, it still influences BP as it contributes to loss

Comment: Why not just ignore those samples? I mean remove those samples from the corpus.

Comment: thanks, but it's multi-label problem, which means each sample has all labels, but some labels should be ignored in training, that's what I want :)

Comment: Then you can transfer the multi-label problem into a one hot problem.